# Получить общий свободный объем для каждого диска через WMI на C#

Tags: c#, wmi

Необходимо через WMI узнать сколько свободного места есть на каждом, физическом HDD. Заранее неизвестно сколько подключено HDD и сколько разделов на каждом диске.
Набросал такой код.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher wdSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

foreach (ManagementObject drive in wdSearcher.Get())
{
    Driver driver = new Driver();
    driver.Model = drive["Model"].ToString().Trim();
    driver.Type = drive["InterfaceType"].ToString().Trim();
    driver.Partitions = byte.Parse(drive["Partitions"].ToString().Trim());
    driver.TotalSpace = long.Parse(drive["Size"].ToString().Trim());
}

ManagementObjectSearcher lgSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");

iDriveIndex = 0;
byte partitionCount = 1;

foreach (ManagementObject drive in lgSearcher.Get())
{
    if (iDriveIndex > DriverList.Count) break;

    if (partitionCount > DriverList[iDriveIndex].Partitions)
    {
        iDriveIndex++;
        partitionCount = 1;
    }

    long freeSpace = 0;

    try
    {
        freeSpace = long.Parse(drive["FreeSpace"].ToString().Trim());
    }
    catch
    { continue; }

    DriverList[iDriveIndex].FreeSpace += freeSpace;
    partitionCount++;
}
```

Но проблема в том, что в переменную `Partition` возвращается число 3 с учетом скрытых разделов. А в `Win32_LogicalDisk` этих разделов понятное дело нет.

Comment: https://hintdesk.com/2011/07/15/c-get-free-space-of-network-harddisk/

Answer (score 0):

Используя класс [Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisktopartition), который позволяет связать между собой логические диски и разделы. От раздела легко перейти к физическому диску по индексу. Как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{    

    class Program
    {

        public struct WmiSelectionCondition
        {
            public string PropertyName { get; set; }
            public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
        }

        public struct LogicalDiskToPartition
        {
            public WmiSelectionCondition PartitionSelectionCondition { get; set; }
            public WmiSelectionCondition LogicalDiskSelectionCondition { get; set; }
        }

        //получает таблицу соответствия логических дисков и разделов
        public static List<LogicalDiskToPartition> GetPartitionMap()
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                "SELECT Antecedent,Dependent FROM Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
                );
            LogicalDiskToPartition item;
            WmiSelectionCondition condition;
            List<LogicalDiskToPartition> list = new List<LogicalDiskToPartition>();
            string text;
            string[] arr, arr2;

            using (mos)
            {
                var moc = mos.Get();                

                foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
                {
                    item = new LogicalDiskToPartition();

                    //Распарсим значения ref-полей класса Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition
                    //Они имеют формат Class.Property="Value"

                    text = mo["Antecedent"].ToString(); //Partition reference
                    arr = text.Split(new char[] { '=', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    if (arr.Length >= 2)
                    {
                        arr2 = arr[0].Split(new char[] { ':', '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        condition = new WmiSelectionCondition();
                        if (arr2.Length == 0) condition.PropertyName = "";
                        else condition.PropertyName = arr2[arr2.Length - 1];
                        condition.PropertyValue = arr[1];
                        item.PartitionSelectionCondition = condition;
                    }

                    text = mo["Dependent"].ToString(); //Logical disk reference
                    arr = text.Split(new char[] { '=', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    if (arr.Length >= 2)
                    {
                        arr2 = arr[0].Split(new char[] { ':', '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        condition = new WmiSelectionCondition();
                        if (arr2.Length == 0) condition.PropertyName = "";
                        else condition.PropertyName = arr2[arr2.Length - 1];
                        condition.PropertyValue = arr[1];
                        item.LogicalDiskSelectionCondition = condition;
                    }

                    list.Add(item);
                }

            }
            return list;
        }

        //выборка значения свойства из WMI-класса по заданному условию
        public static object WmiPerformSelection(string prop_to_select,string classname, WmiSelectionCondition condition )
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                String.Format(
                "SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = '{3}'",
                prop_to_select, classname, condition.PropertyName, condition.PropertyValue)
                );

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
            {                
                foreach (var prop in mo.Properties)
                {                    
                    if (prop.Value != null) return prop.Value;                    
                }                
            }
            return null;
        }

        //вычисляет свободное место на диске, заданном индексом
        public static long CalcDriveFreeSpace(List<LogicalDiskToPartition> map, int index)
        {
            long result = 0;

            foreach (var item in map)
            {
                object val = WmiPerformSelection("DiskIndex", "Win32_DiskPartition", item.PartitionSelectionCondition);
                if (val == null) continue;
                int item_index = Convert.ToInt32(val);
                if (item_index != index) continue;

                val = WmiPerformSelection("FreeSpace", "Win32_LogicalDisk", item.LogicalDiskSelectionCondition);
                if (val == null) continue;
                long freespace = Convert.ToInt64(val);
                result += freespace;   
            }

            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            var map = GetPartitionMap();           

            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
               String.Format(
               "SELECT Caption, Index, Size FROM Win32_DiskDrive")
               );

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
            {
                object val = mo["Index"];
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(val);

                string caption="";
                if (mo["Caption"] != null) caption = mo["Caption"].ToString();

                string size="0";
                if (mo["Size"] != null) size = mo["Size"].ToString();

                long freespace = CalcDriveFreeSpace(map, index);                

                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} bytes total; {2} bytes free",caption, size, freespace);                
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```